# handleGetURLEvent: doesn't get called in Safari Extension Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, macos-sierra, safari-extension

I'm developing Safari extension for Mac with Google authorization ("GTMAppAuth" pod). But I can't handle authorization in Safari extension target:

```
- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event
           withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
```

I've added URL to .plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>MyURL</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I have set event handler in singleton, because it's no AppDelegate in Extension

```
+ (Singleton *)sharedSingleton 
{
    static Singleton *singleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
        {
            singleton = [[Singleton alloc] init];
            NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager =
            [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
            [appleEventManager setEventHandler:self
                                   andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:)
                                 forEventClass:kInternetEventClass
                                    andEventID:kAEGetURL];
        });

    return singleton;
}
```

My method for handling:

```
- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event
           withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString *URLString = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
    [_currentAuthorizationFlow resumeAuthorizationFlowWithURL:URL];
}
```

Anyway it's not getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days I found a solution for me.
I'm using Application group to pass authorization URL to extension.
After user is pressing signIn button I'm scheduling NSTimer. When user signed in main application is loading and handling redirect URL. In that method it's saving to Group's UserDefaults.

```
- (void)p_signInToGoogleWithSuccessBlock:(void(^)(NSString *email, NSString *token, NSError *error))successBlock
{
    //This method will call in Extension 
    OIDAuthorizationRequest *request = [self createGoogleAuthorizationRequest];

    _currentAuthorizationFlow =
    [OIDAuthState authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest:request
                                                   callback:^(OIDAuthState *_Nullable authState,
                                                          NSError *_Nullable error)
     {
         if (authState)
         {
             //User authorized
         }
         else
         {
             //User dismissed authorization
         }
     }];
         //Start timer to check group for authorization URL
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                repeats:YES
                                  block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer)
                                    {
                                       //Check group for authorization URL
                                        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:kGroupID];
                                        NSString *authorizationString = [defaults objectForKey:kAuthorizationURL];

                                        if (authorizationString != nil)
                                        {
                                            NSURL *authorizationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:authorizationString];
                                            [self.currentAuthorizationFlow resumeAuthorizationFlowWithURL:authorizationURL];
                                            [timer invalidate];
                                        }
                                    }];
}
```

Setting redirect handler in main application's AppDelegate. You have to set it BEFORE application launched:

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager =
    [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    [appleEventManager setEventHandler:self
                           andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:)
                         forEventClass:kInternetEventClass
                            andEventID:kAEGetURL];
}
```

Handling redirect URL in main application's AppDelegate and save URL to group:

```
- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event
       withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString *URLString = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:kGroupID];
    [defaults setObject:URLString forKey:kAuthorizationURL];
}
```

So, through App Groups I'm passing Google Redirect URL to Safari extension for next authorization steps. If someone knows another way to do it, I will be glad to check it.